# More efficient way than base64 to embed binary data in an html page

Tags: html

I am looking for a more efficient way to embed binary data in an html page than base64. I realise I could make use of base64 variants, such as ascii85/base85. is there something that approximates the densitiy of the raw input?

Comment: Are you aware that web servers generally compress (as in, gzip) HTML pages before sending them to a browser?

Comment: Yes I am very familiar how modern web works. My question is very specific for very specific reasons - the html page is not transmitted over HTTP.

Comment: Any constraints on browser support, or the size of JS libraries?

Comment: No particular constraints at this early stage of exploration of the possibilities.